# Не получается получить страницу instagram на сервере

Tags: python, сервер, requests, instagram

На локале все получается выдает нужную страницу, но на сервере нет, код одинаковый.
У обоих `<html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in client-root">`, но на локале выдает страницу пользователя, а на сервере страницу для регистрации. Как мне это исправить?
Вот заголовки которые я прокидываю

```
HEADERS = {
    'accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36'
}
```

`?__a=1` Так же работает только на локале

код:

```
import requests


POSTFIX = '?__a=1'
HEADERS = {
    'accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36'
}

def get_json(url):
    page = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    print(page.text)
```

Comment: вы создавали сессию ? requests.Session()

Comment: Вероятно, инстаграм уже забанил ваш сервер за наличие на нём бота

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это решит вашу проблему.

**Import**

```
import requests
```

**Code**

```
    # создаем сессию
    session = requests.Session()
    
    headers = {
            "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36'
                          ' (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'}
    # дальше отправляем данные для авторизации
    def auth():
        login = ''  # логин аккаунта
        password = ''  # пароль аккаунта
        
        data = {"username": login, "password": password}  # данные для отправки
        url = "https://www.instagram.com/"
        session.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)  # отправка данных
    
    
    def get_json(url):
        page = session.get(url, headers=headers)  # меням requests на session
        print(page.text)
```

Comment: не помогло, работает на локале ,но на сервере нет.Это не зависит от сервера ,тк на другом сервере также не получается

Comment: Приложите код пожалуйста полный

Comment: Это весь код. Можно ли залогиниться на сайте requests-ом?

Comment: обновил код, посмотрите

Comment: Не работает, не получается залогиниться, все как раньше, выдает не ту страницу

Comment: думаю вам будет проще сделать это через selenium, я сейчас потыкал действительно будет достаточно сложно это реализовать на requests. Какова ваша основная задача?

Comment: получить ссылки на фото со страницы публикации

Comment: На локале все просто, получаю json и паршу его , но на сервере это сделать не получается

Comment: наверное в данном вопросе я смогу вам помочь только решением на selenium, простите( вы сможете спокойно поставить его на сервер

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Comment: я нашел вот это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58520305/python-instagram-login-using-requests попробуйте данное решение у меня вроде как работает

Answer (score 0):

Это мне помогло `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66355609/cant-get-the-instagram-page/66357784#66357784`, Instagram запрещает все диапазоны IP-адресов центров обработки данных и перенаправляет для входа в систему.